# Is HTTPS required on container running on Azure linux app service

Tags: azure, nginx

I am having following setup, I have deployed public-facing front end application having NGINX web server(with Angular App) on Azure Linux App service, this is part of the docker container. 
I am having another Linux app service having .net API.

Now, in order to force HTTPS, do I need to set up https certificates on Azure App service or should I be setting them in the container too where I have Nginx setup?

Second, where and how should I be mentioning the following rules

```
1. Redirect HTTP request to HTTPS
2. Redirect non-www traffic to www?
```

Answer (score 0):

You try with:

```
 server_name  your_domain.com  *.your_domain.com;
 return 301 https://www.your_domain.com$request_uri;
```

Answer (score 0):

SSL gets off-loaded at the front-end of App Services. That means that SSL requests never get to your Web App. You don't need to (and should not) implement any support for SSL into your app.

http://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/waws/things-you-should-know-web-apps-and-linux#NoSSL